# How to profile my code using my own class that measure time?

Tags: design, c++, profiling

So I working on a project and want to profile my code. I have been using KCachegrind to get general idea of what functions cost the most. But now I want to get the exact time spent on those particular functions. So I decided to measure them manually using `clock_gettime` using object oriented approach. ie. wrap `clock_gettime` function inside a class.

Lets say I want to create a class that handles the measurement of time

```
class measure_time{

    inline int start(){...}; // return ts_start 
    inline int end(){...};   // return ts_end

};
```

Then I use this class to measure time across the projects. When I am about to measure I have to create instance of measure_time per each classes of my project. ie: Lets say I have class A, class B, class C etc in my project.

```
// A.h
class A{
   void f();
   void f_1();
   measure_time mt;
}
// A.cpp
void A::f(){
    // does some work 
}

void A::f_1(){

    // measure time start
    s = mt.start();
    f()
    // measure time end
    e = mt.end();
    //record time
    time = s-e;

}

// B.h
class B{
   void g();
   void g_1();
   measure_time mt;
}
// B.cpp
void B::g(){
    // does some work
}

void B::g_1(){

     // measure time start
    s = mt.start();
    g()
    // measure time end
    e = mt.end();
    //record time
    time = s-e;

}

// C.h
class C{
   void h();
   void h_1();  
   measure_time mt;
}
//C.cpp
void C::h(){
    // does some work
}

void C::h_1(){

     // measure time start
    s = mt.start();
    h()
    // measure time end
    e = mt.end();
    //record time
    time = s-e;

}
```

By this approach I have to define 'measure_time' class in each of the class. So what I wanted was to define the measure_time class only once and use it across the class A, B and C.

Comment: Questions that contain weasel words like "better" are unanswerable.  We don't know what "better" means to you specifically.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I updated my question now .. thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Better.  So what is your actual question?

Comment: @RobertHarvey  "So what I wanted was to define the measure_time class only once and use it across the class A, B and C." my concern is that I am defining `measure_time` class in each `class A, B and C` and wondering if that is right approach. I think defining `class measure_time` once and reusing it better approach. So I guess my question is how to do it in a way I only have to define `class measure_time` once and re-use it.

Comment: @RobertHarvey let me know if I am still not struggling to explain my question :p because it has happened to me before .. and I want to learn a proper approach to ask question.

Comment: The way you find an answer to your question is to first determine what "better" means to you.  One you know that, I think the "proper" approach will become obvious.

Comment: I think you're confusing classes with object instances;  you should only have one `measure_time` class, but it's perfectly valid to use that one class to create several object instances in other classes.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Hmmm I not really (about class and object). I want to create only one instance of the class rather then multiple because why create multiple instance if only one instance does the job (this is my reason behind trying to create only one class)

Comment: That's the correct reasoning.

Comment: @RobertHarvey When I say " this is my reason behind trying to create only one class" I actually meant "this is my reason behind trying to create only one object " sorry abt that

Comment: So did you meant something like this? https://ideone.com/SDrzRP

Comment: I don't think your timer needs to know about your object either.  Just start your timer, call whatever methods on your objects you wish to time, and stop the timer when the method returns.

Comment: @solti: Meta-question: What is the reason why you want to do these measurements? Is it because you want to find ways to reduce the execution time, or some other reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

t seems as if you're trying to use one timer to measure execution time across three objects? If that's what you're doing, your classes shouldn't know *anything* about that timer.

Set up a timer in another class, start it, execute your three objects, stop the timer, and see the result. An object should only have its own timer if it's responsible for timing *itself.*

Comment: I am still having difficulty understanding one this. When I do 1) starting timer  2) execute three objects 3) stop timer. Lets say one of class's function (A) calls other (B,C)class functions. Then from main I execute A's function that class other (B,C)class function. How can I measure the execution time of other  (B,C)class function  since this measurement from main will only give time of A's function which is combination of time executing B and C's function . eg : `A () { B.g(); C.h();}`

Comment: If class R containing functions B and C needs to be timed independently, then put a timer into class R.  Wouldn't it be easier to just run a profiler on this code?

Comment: that is correct .. I got carried away for sec there